# Streaming audio in my Website

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio, audio-streaming

I am making a fan site for a music artist and I am having trouble with finding a reliable way to stream the music on the site. I have tried many different methods and none are giving me the results I am looking for.

I need the player to accept a direct URL as the source for the audio. As well as working on as many operating systems/browsers as possible. All of my audios are in mp3 format.
I currently have it working, but for some reason it seems like a hit or miss when the page loads some of the players work, some don't. 
I have tried different hosting services and that didn't make a difference, so the issue is within the player itself.

I have modded this player to use in my site. This is the best of the many that I've tried, but if only it would load the songs more reliably I would be happy.

http://designmodo.com/audio-player/

And this is my audio tag in html.

```
 <div class="audio-player">
                <h1>  Yea</h1> <h2>  May 23, 2016</h2>
                <h3>          Lil Uzi Vert         </h3>
                <img class="cover" src="../playerimgs/cover.png">
                <audio  preload   class="part14" src="http://dopefile.pk/mp3embed-df1s7uzu0d6b.mp3" type="audio/mp3" controls="controls"></audio>

            </div>
```

I have many players on the same page. Some of them work on initial page load, and some of them require many refresh clicks to actually load. This is not practical.

So I am looking for one of two things,

**1- How to fix my player so it is always working on initial load. 
2- A different music player that is more reliable.**

I know this idea is not impossible, but I am not having any luck finding the best way to do this. I've searched and used over a dozen different players and none work as much as this one. The only problem I am having with this setup is the music players not always working for some odd reason.

I can add the javascript if necessary, but I did not edit that at all.
Also, I do not plan on embedding other players in my site. I have tried this already and it is not efficient at all.

Thanks for any help or advise.

This website is a great example of what I would like my player to be like.

https://jams.to/

And this is my temporary page that I am working with my players on,

http://www.luvallday.com/Posts/Allsongs.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I've done some work integrating audio into HTML5 games/interactive experiences, and the best library I've worked with so far is [Howler](http://goldfirestudios.com/blog/104/howler.js-Modern-Web-Audio-Javascript-Library). Very clean and easy to use API, and it performed very well cross-browser.

Comment: I just tried howler and it doesn't play on my phone. It probably does well on desktops, but my audience will be majorly users on mobile device. Even though I love the simplicity, this isn't going to work for me.

Comment: It should work on mobile, I've used it across a wide range of android and iphone devices. The one caveat is that playing must be directly triggered by a user interaction on iphone

Comment: Well, all my songs will only be played once the user presses the play button, so that caveat is not a problem. If you could help me get it to work I'd appreciate that. I'm gonna update my question with how I used Howler. EDIT: it seems the issue was firefox on my android device, not the howler player. I'll mess with it a little more and see what I can do.

Comment: hey do you know if you can add a seek bar to the howler player? I been searching around but can't find an example of anyone who did that and the documentation doesn't state a function or method to do this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your music to play automatically when page loads just add the "autoplay" attribute to the  element tag...

**Example :**

```
<audio class="part14" src="http://dopefile.pk/mp3embed-df1s7uzu0d6b.mp3" type="audio/mp3" controls="controls" autoplay></audio>
```

**Rare but if autoplay fails:**

```
<script>
if(document.readyState == "complete"){

//grab the first player
var player = document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[0];

//play it
player.play();

}
</script>
```

**Or**

If you are more advanced I'd recommend wavesurfer.js , it gives a good music player for visuals ..

Here : http://wavesurfer-js.org/

Comment: I don't want the music to autoplay, I need it to play when the user clicks on the play button.I will try out the wavesurfer player though. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So I found this player call Amazing Audio Player and it is pretty great. It worked well for what I wanted to do.